# js styles don't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I want to color background of blocks with `features__box` class but JS doesn't work/ Chrome doesn't recognize any error.

Here is HTML

```
<div class="features__active features__box">
            <h3>Visual Composer</h3>
            <p>TheFox comes with the Visual Composer Plugin. You won’t need to code or to remember any shortcodes with our. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="features__box">
            <h3>Responsive</h3>
            <p>TheFox comes with the Visual Composer Plugin. You won’t need to code or to remember any shortcodes with our. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="features__box">
            <h3>Retina Ready</h3>
            <p>TheFox comes with the Visual Composer Plugin. You won’t need to code or to remember any shortcodes with our. </p>
        </div>
```

THis is JS :

```
var feature_i = document.querySelectorAll('.features__box');

feature_i.addEventListener('click', function(){

    for( var i = 0; i < fearture_i.length; i++) {
        feature_i[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

});
```

By default the background of each item is white. I want it to toggle.
Please, help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method

Answer (score 2):

The event listeners need to be inside your loop and attached to each object element.

```
var feature_i = document.querySelectorAll('.features__box');

for (var i = 0; i < feature_i.length; i++) {
    feature_i[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // where "this" refers to feature_i[i]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your for loop isn't correct. You're missing the .length property in the second part of your loop setup.

```
for( var i = 0; i < fearture_i; i++) {
    feature_i[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in the spelling of **feature_i** inside the loop where you're writting **fearture_i**. In addition you need to change it to **feature_i.length**.

There is an easier way with JQuery. You could do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".features__box").click(function(){
      $(".features__box").css("background-color", "red");
  });

});
```

**Edit** 
In order to toggle the red color chage the function as:

```
$(".features__box").click(function(e){
  $(".features__box").css("background-color", "white");
  var current = e.target;
  current.style.background = "red";
});
```

Comment: how to toggle class 'red' ? I want each item to become red when  I click , and one that is currently active to hide that style

Comment: Do you mean only one red item each time?

Comment: I mean when I click on a div block it becomes red, the next time I click another div with the same class, the color of the previously clicked dissapears and appers on another div that is currently clicked